# jQuery UI Droppable, do not propagate event over specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, event-propagation

I'm working on an interface where users can drop "widgets" on "droppable zones" in the page.

The widgets are stored in a div absolutely positionned in the page (on the left, with z-index:1)
The droppables zones are in another div in the page.

**The problem is :**
When i drag a widget from the left column to a droppable zone in the page, the droppable event is catch even through the left column div. I want to stop the droppable event when the user drags over the left colum, but keep the event when the user is out of the left column.

### HTML

```
<div id="left">
  <div class="dragMe">Drop me on Yellow</div>
  <div class="dragMe">Drop me on Yellow</div>
  <div class="dragMe">Drop me on Yellow</div>
  <div class="dragMe">Drop me on Yellow</div>
</div>

<div id="right">
  <div class="dropOnMe"></div>
  <div class="dropOnMe"></div>
  <div class="dropOnMe"></div>
  <div class="dropOnMe"></div>
  <div class="dropOnMe"></div>
  <div class="dropOnMe"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 220px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropOnMe {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.dragMe {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: move;
  font-family: tahoma;
}

.ui-droppable-hover {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

### JS

```
$(function() {

  $('#left .dragMe').draggable(
    {
      helper: 'clone',
      opacity: 0.5,
      appendTo: 'body',
      zIndex: 11
    }
  );

  $('#right .dropOnMe').droppable(
    {
        drop: function( event, ui ) {

          console.log(event);

        }
      }
    );

});
```

Check example : http://jsbin.com/judajucuxu/1/edit?html,output

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in *JavaScript* code. The problem is in your *CSS*.

Your left side is always a part of droppable area, because positioned absolutely.

It woks if you fix it in this [example](http://jsbin.com/vugomoneka/edit?html,css,output).

```
#left {
      position: relative;
}
```

Besides, I wouldn't recommend using jQuery UI library for that, because all contemporary browsers has [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

*EDIT 1:*

You could also move the right on the width of the left container, to prevent interaction:

```
#right{
    margin-left: 230px;
}
```

*EDIT 2:*

You could also do fancy stuff, once you say you can't change HTML.

Try to detect the cursor offset and decided if you ready to drop your element:

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {
     if (event.pageX > $('#left').width() + 100) {
         console.log(event);
     }
}
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/rusugufige/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, but i need to keep the left column in absolute position. Do you think there is no solution if i keep absolute position ?

Comment: And thank you also for your advice to use drag n drop API, i'll check on this side also.

Comment: You could move the right part on the size more, so it wouldn't interact with the left. Take a look at edit part.

Comment: Yes sure, that does also the trick. But the interface i'm working on have this left colum OVER the droppable divs, and i can't change that behaviour. Thank you anyway for your time and your help.

Comment: Take a look at my other edit. It's possible to do my checking on the cursor position.

Comment: Ok, that was a solution i hoped not to use, but it seems there is no other solution. Thank you for helping me, i'll try to do something in this way.

Comment: @wawawoom I would recommend, if possible, produce proper HTML output.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: You mentioned that you have to keep left column absolutely positioned. I would change that in order to avoid fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
$('#left .dragMe').draggable({
       refreshPositions: true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not stop the propagation through the left column.